# SQL: Include column in result set when not null

Tags: sql-server

**ShipmentRouteInfo** Table

```
ShipmentID      OriginSite      Stop1       Stop2       DestinationSite     Quantity
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1           A               B           C           D                   10          //Taking all stops
    2           E               B           NULL        F                   20          //Shipment goes from E to F via B
    3           G               NULL        NULL        H                   30          //Shipment goes from G to H, no stops taken
```

I wish to transform this table into.

```
ShipmentID      OriginStopDestination           Site        PathID          Quantity
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               Origin                          A           A_D             10
1               Stop1                           B           A_D             10
1               Stop2                           C           A_D             10
1               Destination                     D           A_D             10
2               Origin                          E           E_F             20  
2               Stop1                           B           E_F             20
2               Destination                     F           E_F             20
3               Origin                          G           G_H             30  
3               Destination                     H           G_H             30
```

I want to generate `Path ID` for every shipment in this format `OriginSite_DestinationSite` and also generate one separate row for each origin site, stop1, stop2, destination site.

This is what I have done so far.

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT Z.ShipmentID, Z.OriginStopDestination, Z.Site, Z.PathID, Z.Quantity
FROM (   
    SELECT A.ShipmentID, 'Origin' as OriginStopDestination, A.OriginSite as Site, CONCAT(CONCAT(A.OriginSite, '_'),A.DestinationSite) as PathID, A.Quantity
    FROM ShipmentRouteInfo A
    UNION
    SELECT B.ShipmentID, 'Destination' as OriginStopDestination, B.DestinationSite as Site, CONCAT(CONCAT(B.OriginSite, '_'),B.DestinationSite) as PathID, B.Quantity
    FROM ShipmentRouteInfo B
) AS Z 
ORDER BY Z.ShipmentID
```

Gives me....

```
ShipmentID      OriginStopDestination           Site        PathID          Quantity
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               Origin                          A           A_D             10
1               Destination                     D           A_D             10
2               Origin                          E           E_F             20  
2               Destination                     F           E_F             20
3               Origin                          G           G_H             30  
3               Destination                     H           G_H             30
```

How should I modify my query to include stop information as well?

Please don't remove `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT Z.ShipmentID, Z.OriginStopDestination, Z.Site, Z.PathID, Z.Quantity` from my query I need it for some other purpose. Suggest me how should I modify the inner query block.

Comment: side note: The fact that you are using `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT` means that you don't need it nor do you need the order by clause. I'll bet you want to use this query as a derived table or a view or something like this. You should know that tables in relational database are considered unsorted by nature, that's why SQL server will not let you use the `order by` clause without specifying `top` as well.

Comment: Any other answers pls which comes close to using UNION and doing minimal modifications

Comment: Why can't you UNION Stop1 and Stop2 the same way you UNIONed Origin and Destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a catch, because this seems rather obvious to me, but the answer you seem to want is this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT Z.ShipmentID, Z.OriginStopDestination, Z.Site, Z.PathID, Z.Quantity
FROM (   
    SELECT A.ShipmentID, 'Origin' as OriginStopDestination, A.OriginSite as Site, CONCAT(CONCAT(A.OriginSite, '_'),A.DestinationSite) as PathID, A.Quantity
    FROM ShipmentRouteInfo A
    UNION
SELECT B.ShipmentID, 'Stop1' as OriginStopDestination, B.OriginSite as Site, CONCAT(CONCAT(B.OriginSite, '_'),B.DestinationSite) as PathID, B.Quantity
FROM ShipmentRouteInfo B
WHERE B.Stop1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT C.ShipmentID, 'Stop2' as OriginStopDestination, C.DestinationSite as Site, CONCAT(CONCAT(C.OriginSite, '_'),C.DestinationSite) as PathID, C.Quantity
FROM ShipmentRouteInfo C
WHERE C.Stop2 IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT D.ShipmentID, 'Destination' as OriginStopDestination, D.DestinationSite as Site, CONCAT(CONCAT(D.OriginSite, '_'),D.DestinationSite) as PathID, D.Quantity
FROM ShipmentRouteInfo D
) AS Z 
ORDER BY Z.ShipmentID
```

At least, this query continues the logic you started to use and otherwise makes minimal changes to your existing query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UnPivot as below:

```
Select ShipmentId, originstopdestination, [Site], [Path], Quantity from 
(Select *, [Path] = concat(originsite,'-',destinationsite) from #shipments ) a
unpivot ([Site] for [OriginStopDestination] in ([Originsite],[stop1],[stop2], [DestinationSite])) p
```

Output as below:

```
+------------+-----------------------+-----------------+------+----------+
| ShipmentId | originstopdestination |      Site       | Path | Quantity |
+------------+-----------------------+-----------------+------+----------+
|          1 | A                     | Originsite      | A-D  |       10 |
|          1 | B                     | stop1           | A-D  |       10 |
|          1 | C                     | stop2           | A-D  |       10 |
|          1 | D                     | DestinationSite | A-D  |       10 |
|          2 | E                     | Originsite      | E-F  |       20 |
|          2 | B                     | stop1           | E-F  |       20 |
|          2 | F                     | DestinationSite | E-F  |       20 |
|          3 | G                     | Originsite      | G-H  |       30 |
|          3 | H                     | DestinationSite | G-H  |       30 |
+------------+-----------------------+-----------------+------+----------+
```

Comment: I actually want OriginSite, stop1, stop2, DestinationSite under originstopdestination column.

Comment: Updated query accordingly

Comment: Could you please show me how to use UnPivot function with minimal changes in what I already have.

Comment: What I pasted here is trimmed version of my query. It is just too difficult to change my original query. Could you please just modify that query I have, Use UNION as it is.

Comment: UnPivot is the actual approach for your query... To use your original query put all your query in a cte and use that cte in #shipments as in my query